# Free software for Windows Mobile application development

Tags: windows-mobile

I hope this question is not too off-topic, if it is this post can be deleted.

I am a programmer/webdeveloper in mainly Java and PHP. I have some free time on my hand and want to play a little with mobile application development.

Now the [first links](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WM6YourFirstApp) I found on Google tells me how to build an application using Visual Studio.

I am only going to play around with it for a few days so I am not planning on buying that package just for that. My webdevelopment and programming is done in Dreamweaver and Eclipse.

Are there any free alternatives to develop WM applications? I doubt that there is any eclipse version that deals with WM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-windows-ce/) for Open Source Windows Mobile development.

Comment: Thanks this looks nice, I will take a closer look at it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of Open Source tools to develop Windows Phone 7 apps, however, if you are just looking for **FREE** tools, the [Windows 7 tools](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7/) come with Visual Studio Express, which is everything you need to get started writing for the phone.

Comment: I am currently running windows mobile 6.x. Will these tools work for that also?

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't free develoepr tools for WM6.x development. Not unless you want to use the command line compiler.